# Text fade with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, fade

I don't understand why this isn't working? I'm just trying to make quotes fade in and out of this one spot, but nothing shows up? I put the script at the bottom before the `</body>` where it's supposed to go. What am I doing wrong here?

The HTML

```
<div class="quoteContainer">
<span class="quotes">first quote</span>
<span class="quotes">second quote</span>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.quoteContainer {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #444444;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.quotes {display: none;}​
```

The Javascript

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(1000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();​
</script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you put that script in the head, and that's not a DOM ready handler, it's just an immediately invoked function, so it runs before the elements are available in the DOM. Add document.ready !

Comment: Point proven, works in fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/U6ZcK/

Comment: To debug JS scripts, look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). There's an invisible Unicode character at the end of the script that causes a syntax error.

Comment: @adeneo You didn't copy-paste it correctly. Also, the OP says *"I put the script at the bottom before the </body> where it's supposed to go. "*

Comment: @Juhana - didn't read that far, and I removed the unicode character as it shows up in jsfiddle, they sometimes sneak in when posting code in SO, so I assumed it wasn't there in the originale code, as it would show up in my editor etc. but if the script is at the bottom the unicode character is probably the issue !

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thanks so much!!! Now I just gotta figure out why it won't work when I have a bx-slider in the same page as the quote fade... :(